# Spring Wound timer on stove top

Tags: electrical, stove, timer

I have an electric stove.  Occasionally someone in the house (myself included) may forgetfully leave it on after finishing cooking a meal.  I'd like to wire a spring wound timer to the appliance.  The stove is on a 40 amp breaker and I can only find spring wound timers rated up to 20 amps.

What is a non-prevagen solution?

Comment: Does the timer need to be spring wound?  You want the timer to turn off the whole stove?  If so you will need to use the timer every time you want to use the stove.

Comment: There are a variety of unattended stove shut off options, typically pitched towards the more age-experienced.

Comment: Yes, we plan to use the timer every time we use the stove-it will be installed in close proximity.

Comment: What is a "non-prevagen solution"? Is this something to do with being a meat-eater and deciding to give up the tasty stuff for vegetables only?

Comment: There are actually a lot of products (some quite spendy) aimed at the elder/forgetful/perhaps declining into dementia market for shutting off stoves after a time.

Comment: If you're going to insist on spring wound, use one to control the coil on a 50A two-pole relay/contactor as two separate parts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because appliance usage and modification isn't home improvement per the definition on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Connect a relay (contactor) to the timer so that the timer controls the current flow in the coil.  Connect the relay contacts to the stove.

The timer when started, energizes teh coil which activates the relay to start the stove.  And vice versa.

Ensure that the relay can handle 40A+.

Answer (score 2):

They actually make such devices:

https://www.cookstop.com/

https://iguardfire.com/

Not spring wound, but...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set a mechanical or electrical timer when you start cooking. Have it go off about an hour after you expect to be finished. It will serve as a reminder to check the stove. Most stoves have a timer built in that would serve the purpose.

Comment: Excellent idea +1. I think, however, that the issue is that someone is using the timer to cook, but forgets to turn the stove off when the timer goes off/food is removed from cooking. We seem to be looking for an automated solution for forgetfulness...

Comment: Because if you walk away, leave the house, go to sleep far from the kitchen, pass out - it doesn't work.